# php compare/match range of values

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, match, associative-array

I have an array to which I need to compare data from mysql. Usually I'm doing a straight comparison so I can do an `if ($array[$i]===$mysql[$i])`, but I do have one instance where I need to match it against a range of numbers (ex. 18-19, 20-24, etc). I looked into preg_match & preg_grep, but they don't seem to be what I want…

I just need a true/false result from the comparison.

The part of the array I'm trying to match against looks like this:

```
"age"=>array(
        '18-19'=>array('total'=>0,'completed'=>0),
        '20-24'=>array('total'=>0,'completed'=>0),
        '25-29'=>array('total'=>0,'completed'=>0),
        '30-34'=>array('total'=>0,'completed'=>0),
        '35-39'=>array('total'=>0,'completed'=>0),
        '40-44'=>array('total'=>0,'completed'=>0),
        '45-49'=>array('total'=>0,'completed'=>0),
        '50-54'=>array('total'=>0,'completed'=>0),
        '55-59'=>array('total'=>0,'completed'=>0)
),"race"=>array(
        "White"=>array('total'=>0,'completed'=>0),
        "Black"=>array('total'=>0,'completed'=>0),
        "Hispanic"=>array('total'=>0,'completed'=>0),
        "Asian"=>array('total'=>0,'completed'=>0),
        "Pacific Islander"=>array('total'=>0,'completed'=>0),
        "Multiracial"=>array('total'=>0,'completed'=>0),
        "Other"=>array('total'=>0,'completed'=>0)
)
```

Is there a clean way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you build an array out of your db data similar to the schema of your `$array` and in the end try to `if($array==$mysqldata)`? Btw... How does your table look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```php
list($min,$max) = explode('-', $array[$i]);
if ($mysql[$i] >= $min && $mysql[$i] <= $max) ...
```

Comment: @nachito: Thank you. I adhere to the [KISS principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). :-)

Comment: @jacob: Oops! Had my variables backward. Fixed.

Comment: I am fond of KISS. P.S. Switching those variables helped a lot lol

Comment: @jacob: Yeah, [KISS rocks](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c6/Kiss_saunaopenair2010.jpg)! :-D

Answer (score 1):

PHP's [range() function](https://www.php.net/range) might be useful:

```
foreach ($array['age'] as $ageRange => $something) {
    list($start, $limit) = explode('-', $ageRange);
    foreach (range($start, $limit) as $age) {
        // compare
    }
}
```